# Meaning of "stay way in droves"

Tags: meaning, idioms

What does "*stay way in droves*" mean in the context of [this passage](http://www.actualfreedom.com.au/richard/selectedcorrespondence/sc-belonging.htm)? I cannot find a suitable definition from Oxford.

> GARY: I would welcome any comments either you or other participants
> have about the topic currently under discussion. I would be
> interested, for instance, in knowing how your own conduct socially and
> in terms of intimate, emotional connection has changed since you have
> been living in Actual Freedom compared with your previous life as a
> ‘normal’, care-worn person.
>
> RICHARD: Ahh ... the change from being a care-worn person to being a
> care-free person means that social interaction has changed from normal
> to actual (from friendship to fellowship) which is a change from being
> affectively intimate (a separative connection) to being actually
> intimate (an inseparate association) and, as a result, a change from
> being commiserative to being dissolutive and thus a change from
> complaintive to acclamatory and/or from condolatory to laudatory (from
> grievance to panegyrical) ... what others would call being
> ‘optimistic’, or ‘positive’, or ‘up-beat’, and so on.
>
> Mostly people **stay way in droves**.

Comment: Perhaps a typo for "Mostly people *stay away* in droves."

Comment: Why was this closed? It seems like a reasonable question.

Comment: @Pete Most practised native speakers would be expected to spot that 'stay way' is either a typo for or an unfamiliar colloquial variant of 'stay away'. If the question were << Why do people use the illogical expression 'stay away in droves'? >>, the question is still arguably lacking readily available research. The first hit I get in a Google search for "stay away in droves" is this [2012 Barry Popik article](https://www.barrypopik.com/index.php/new_york_city/entry/the_public_stayed_away_in_droves) mentioning 'Goldwynisms'.

Comment: I disagree. It only makes sense if you are already familiar with the Goldwynism. To those who haven't heard it,   a misprinted version would be totally confusing.

Comment: @Pete The fact that there are a mere handful of Google hits for "stay way in droves" would be enough for most proficient Anglophones to judge this to be nonstandard and quite possibly a typo. 'Stay away' has over 130m hits, so the corrected "stay away in droves" shouldn't be too hard for a proficient native speaker to suspect and check for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a typo.  It should be  "stay away".

There is an idiom "people are coming in droves"  for a popular thing, e.g. a movie that everyone wants to see.   A Drove is a word for a flock of animals.

Sam Goldwyn was famous for alleged verbal gaffes, known as [Goldwynisms](https://www.cobbles.com/simpp_archive/goldwynisms_kanin.htm). He [allegedly said](https://www.barrypopik.com/index.php/new_york_city/entry/the_public_stayed_away_in_droves) of an unsuccessful movie "They are staying away in droves."  This is an absurdity. You can't call an absence of people a drove.  But sometimes people deliberately copy the phrase trying to be funny.

This person copied it, but omitted the letter *a*.

Comment: There's a related Yogi-ism "Nobody goes there any more. It's too crowded."

Comment: Also 'underehelmed' or 'not particular gruntled'